# regex for extracting all urls from string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract URL from a piece of string I have different posts that contains URL in their message. I've prepared a pattern to match but it's not working properly.

**Tried Regex**

```
$pattern1= '%\b((https?://)|(www\.)|(^[\D]+\.))[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))%';
$pattern2= '%\b^((https?://)|(www\.)|(^[a-z]+\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%';
```

**CODE**

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $resultcount; $i ++ ) {
    $pattern = '%\b^((https?://)|(www\.)|(^[a-z]+\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%';
    $message = (string)$result[$i]['message'];
    preg_match_all($pattern,$message,$match);
    print_r($match);
    }
```

A Example of my post like this

> "This is just a post to test regex for extracting URL
>   http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlw32af
>   https://instagram.com/oscar/ en.wikipedia.org"

Post may have comma or may not have comma for multiple URLs

Thank you people :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
\b(?:https?://)?(?:(?i:[a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b
```

---

Broken down, this says:

```
\b                   # a word boundary
(?:https?://)?       # http:// or https://, optional
(?:(?i:[a-z]+\.)+)   # any subdomain before
[^\s,]+              # neither whitespace nor comma
\b                   # another word boundary
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/w7Z6PV/7/).

Comment: hey thanks but I need to extract all URLs mentioned.. Could help me for this?

Comment: yeah it's works like charm but if the urls has ',' then it's taking all urls into one any fix for comma separated urls?

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid: Check the newly updated answer - please put your requirements more clearly in the first place :) https://regex101.com/r/9hhKLS/3

Answer (score 0):

First I am analyse some URL of wikipedia which is clearly show in attach screenshot then write regex !

```
https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/(.*)
```

[image]