# regex for extracting all urls from string excluding period for terminating strings

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to extract URL from a piece of string I have different posts that contains URL in their message. I've prepared a pattern to match but it's not working properly. I have asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201777/regex-for-extracting-all-urls-from-string) but forgot to add this case in that so I'm asking a new question for it.

**Tried Pattern**

```
\b(\.?)(?:https?://)?(?:(?i:[a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b
```

**CODE**

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $resultcount; $i ++ ) {
    $pattern = '%\b(\.?)(?:https?://)?(?:(?i:[a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b%';
    $message = (string)$result[$i]['message'];
    preg_match_all($pattern,$message,$match);
    print_r($match);
    }
```

A Example of my post like this

> "This is just a post to test regex for extracting URL.
>   http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlw32af
>   https://instagram.com/oscar/ en.wikipedia.org"

Post may have comma or may not have comma for multiple URLs and also it is possible that a string and url doesn't have any space in between like

> sometext.http://google.com

[regexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/zueqmp/2)

Thank you people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match strings which are precisely encoded and have formats like an HTTP URL except those fall into IDN categorization:

```
(?i)(?:https?://[^"'\s<>(){}]++|[a-z0-9](?<=\b.)[a-z0-9-]*+(?:\.[a-z-]{2,}+)++(?=[/?"'()\s]|:\d++|\Z)[^"'\s<>(){}]*+)
```

So you will not expect

```
ftp://username:password@ftpserver/folder/
```

to be matched.

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/RpYABl/1)

Answer (score 0):

In your initial question you failed to specify that each "word"
(a part of URL) can contain something other than letters.
Note that your regex contains `[a-z]` which suggests, that you
want to match only URLs, which have "words" composed **entirely**
of letters, without any digits, minus chars or underscores.

Try the following regex:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?i)[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*(?:[.\/](?!http)[a-z0-9_-]+)+\/?(?:\?[^\s,.]+)?
```

Description:

- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` - Optional protocol name.
- `(?i)` - Turn on *case insensitive* option.
- `[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*` - The first "word" of the URL (first a letter,
   then any number of letter, digit, underscore or minus chars).
- `(?:[.\/]` - Non-capturing group: Either a dot or a slash.
- `(?!http)` - then negative lookahead, to block cases when URL starting from
  *http* is immediately preceded by a dot (or a slash).
- `[a-z0-9_-]+)+` - then the next "word" (optional, no requirement to start
  from a letter), all this (non-capturing group) repeated.
- `\/?` - Optional slash, terminating the part before query string (if any).
- `(?:\?[^\s,.]+)?` - Optional non-capturing group for query string.
  It starts from `?` and then a sequence of chars other than space,
  comma or dot.

The above regex does not match the trailing dot, just as you wish.

**Note:**

As I tried this regex under *regex101.com*, I quoted `/` chars contained
in it. You probably can omit this quotation.

Following your comment, I changed the regex, that a "word" can contain also
digits, underscores and minus chars.

Note also that `-` as a **first** or **last** char between `[...]` stands
for itself (opposite to `-` between two other chars, where it means
*from - to*).

Comment: Please provide example source string and describe what is wrong.

Comment: I want to get full url currently I'm getting Ahmedabad.http thats my problem as u can see in my demo.

Comment: I have just added the *negative lookahead*, this should make the thing correct.

Comment: works fine but I'm able to get the url properly see the demo : https://regex101.com/r/zueqmp/3